# Permissions Issues with SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis, windows-server-2008

Please help this beginner here...

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have Visual Studio installed on my PC.

I created my first report and tried to deploy it. It wouldn't deploy and give me a permission error saying that my (domain) account doesn't have permission to do that. So I took the quidk and dirty way out, and made - temporarily - my account an admin in the Windows 2008 Server machine. That worked, and I was able to deploy the report.

Then I sent the URL link to my boss... but now she couldn't run it because of permissions. So I can't follow the same quick and dirty solution and make all users admins in that machine...

So the question is, where and to what should I set the permissions?
Also, I can't find IIS in that server (I tried running inetmgr from the command prompt). Is it possible that it's not running or installed and still the report runs from a browser for me? I can't find the familiar "Add/Remove Windows Components".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a service account and run all of the reports via this account. This can be configured in the Report Configuration tools. Additionally you should add your boss as a Content Viewer/Report Viewer role in the SSRS security section. You can get to this section by navigating to the URL specified when you configured SSRS, usually http://localhost/ReportServer

Comment: Thanks Darren, but I don't follow exactly. Let me tell you what I see when I open Reporting Services Config Mgr. Under 'Service Account' I have 2 options: 'Built-in account' (Network Service / Local System / Local Service) or 'Use another account', in which I can enter any domain or local account. Currently I see there MYDOMAIN\sqluser. Which of all these should I choose? And then, is there anything else to do?

Comment: MYDOMAIN\sqluser is fine as long as it has access to the SQL Server database/tables.  Try logging into the Windows 2008 Server Machine (I assume thats where the database and SSRS are installed) and goto the following URL: http://localhost/ReportServer

There you can add your boss's account DOMAIN\myboss as a Report Viewer and he/she should be able to see the reports.  

For reference you can configure multiple SSRS options by clicking Start -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 -> Configuration Tools -> Report Services Configuration Manager

Comment: Hi Darren: (1) I created the DOMAIN\sqluser user in the new DB, using the DOMAIN\sqluser login. Same results. (2) When I go to http://localhost/reportserverbeta (that's how I called it) it doesn't give me any options to add any users. It just gives me links to directories and data sources that I can use to navigate and get to the reports. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like localhost/reportserverbeta is the Report Server URL (Where your reports and data sources get published to) and not the Report Server Manager URL.  Click Start -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 -> Configuration Tools -> Report Services Configuration Manager and goto Report Manager URL.  This should be different to your Web Service URL.